# how to save the state of a fragment for further use (and to avoid reconstruction)?

Tags: android, fragment

i'm a beginner on android development and the problem really troubles me a lot

now i have code lines like this:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.activity_blank, new WordlistPage(unit, false), "wordlistitems")
    .commit();
```

each time the above section is executed, a new WordlistPage is created and the fragment view is initialized.

for example, currently i am reading the content in fragmentA, and after a while i switch to fragmentB and in one minute i return back to fragmentA.  what i want is that the fragmentA be the same as it was and not be reconstructed.

so any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to create a new fragment each time I switch fragments I've done somethig like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FragmentTag");
if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = new CustomFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag, fragment, "FragmentTag").commit();
} else {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: i don't think this works for me for i have about 10 (or more in the future) fragment types. and i don't want to store all of them using different tags since it can be memory consuming